# "Have you considered to accept or start a bounty"

Tags: discussion, support, accepted-answer

There are some  questions  of  mine  with  answers  which  I  did  not  accept  them,yet.

Some  of  them (but not  all of  them) has  an statement  on the  above  of its title  in the  question  list, as  the  statement  of  the  title  of  this  meta  question.

Can  one  explain  about  this  situation?

Comment: Answer to this meta.SE question might provide (at least partial) explanation: [“Have you considered accepting…” removed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166656) and you can also have a lok at [other posts linked there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/166656). (Or you can simply try to look at a few of results you get after putting ["Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Have+you+considered+accepting+an+answer+or+starting+a+bounty+for+this+question%22) into Google - which is what I did.)